# The Rarest Ingredient of All

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

No tricks here- just a riddle this time!

A frog I have been called,
but I have cell walls.
Threatened am I,
but loved am I;
Alone I hang,
no one can find me.

A friend have I,
the forgotten butterfly.
No one can replicate me,
for I am unique:
Free I must be,
for I perish in captivity.
I will dance for you,
for only a week;
If the world does not improve,
my future is bleak.

To differentiate me from others I'll say
the biggest hint of all:
I am of the color gray.
My spooky physique,
the witch, the toad;
"The rarest ingredient of all"
she would have crowed.

More hints than you deserve
you have been given,
so tell me my name-
and make it thrilling!

Comment: First thing I thought of was https://xkcd.com/1259/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a

> [Ghost Orchid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrophylax_lindenii)

A frog I have been called,
but I have cell walls.

> It is a flower and flowers have cell walls.

Threatened am I,
but loved am I;

> they are very rare.

Alone I hang,
no one can find me.

> They sort of hang on trees, according to Wikipedia.

A friend have I,
the forgotten butterfly.

> Only the giant sphinx moth is able to pollinate ghost orchids due to it's long proboscis(found by google search)

No one can replicate me,
for I am unique:

> Very rare.

Free I must be,
for I perish in captivity.

> It may not survive relocation or captivity.

I will dance for you,
for only a week;

> The bloom time.

If the world does not improve,
my future is bleak.

> Rare and maybe endangered.

To differentiate me from others I'll say
the biggest hint of all:
I am of the color gray.

> That it is.

My spooky physique,

> Ghost Orchid.

the witch, the toad;
"The rarest ingredient of all"
she would have crowed.

> Rare?

Comment: Very quick! That is correct.

Comment: If you want you can un-except my answer, and except it 24-30 hours later, to get more views and votes! Thanks for the puzzle!

Comment: I don't post for glory, that's fine! Well done :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Keep editing to fetch him views and votes :P